# Couldn't Link To Jcenter

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

I uploaded android library to bintray.com and tried to sync it to jCenter.
But I couldn't find "Add To Jcenter" button in bintray.com web UI.
I have a lot of tutorials but there is this button. But on my side, I can't see anything now.
What is the issue? Need help someone.

[image: screenshot of my bintray]

[image: There is no button to add to jCenter.]

If needed, you can find git and see the source code. Thanks.

Comment: I have read a lot of things to link to jCenter but they don't have answer now.

Comment: Why missed "Add To Jcenter" button? This is a maven type repository. So this is a bug of bintray or my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Add To JCenter" is disabled for Enterprise Trial users.
You should be OSS or Premium organization/user in order to link your packages to JCenter.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you're **logged in**. Faced with the same problem, and then found suddenly that I was not logged in :D

Comment: Did I find ***what***?

Comment: "Add To Jcenter" button. This is issue on my side or this is a bug of Bintray.com? What's your idea?

Comment: Are you logged in into Bintray? There is a "Sign In" button in the topbar.

Comment: My problem was that I haven't been logged in. After login the button has appeared,