# How to assume bintray ownership of a repo copied from maven central

Tags: maven, bintray

Bintray jcenter has copied my maven central artifacts into their repository.  I would like to be able to assume ownership, in bintray, of the package, so that I can edit the description and/or hyperlinks and/or other metadata, all of which is currently empty in bintray.  However, the form to request ownership does not work, when you try to send, it gives an error stating some field is missing (without stating which field).  Any ideas?

Comment: I tired with the new UI and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved.  In the end I needed to create a user on bintray, then create a repository for that user, and then that allowed me to select both of those things for the form requesting ownership.

As a newbie to bintray/jcentral none of this was clear or obvious, nor do they do these things for you, nor do they allow you to request ownership first so that they can inform you of these necessary steps to complete.  So it's not particularly user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You [can't link packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41659229/3719024) if you are a trial user. So this might also be an issue if you want to take ownership. If that is not the case then I would contact Bintray support.